# Update SQL dates in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

this is what I need: from the saledate column I need to extract just the month and date and combine with the 2017 year in NewDate column, but I couldn't update. Any suggestions?
[image]

This is the Select statment, I'm trying to update with the alias NewDate and getting an error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out of range value.
This is the data in the saledate column: 1983-09-01 00:00:00.000, I'm trying to make to be the same, just the year to be 2017.

SELECT saledate, renewaldate,CONVERT(date,saledate),  ('2017'+ '-' + LTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(date,saledate)), 1, 5)))) AS NewDate FROM tprogram

UPDATE tprogram
SET renewaldate = ('2017'+ '-' + LTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(date,saledate)), 1, 5))))  FROM tprogram

Comment: Define `but I couldn't update`? Did you get an error?

Comment: Please post you query, sample data and expected output as ***text*** (***not images***)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dateadd()` with the `day()` and `month()` functions like so:

```
select dateadd(day,day(saledate)-1,dateadd(month,month(saledate)-1,'20180101')) as NewDate
```

---

For example:

```
select dateadd(day,day(getdate())-1,dateadd(month,month(getdate())-1,'20180101'))
```

returns: `2018-05-16`

Answer (score 0):

You say you need it with the 2017 year, but you're using a 2018 value. Here's something to get started.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'2017-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(SaleDate))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DAY(SaleDate))) AS NewDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use datefromparts as below:

```
select SaleDate, RenewalDate, Convert(date, SaleDAte), 
    DATEFROMPARTS(2018, datepart(month,SaleDate),DATEPART(day,SaleDate)) as NewDate 
    from yourtable
```

Comment: I think that's 2012+ ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the difference in years back to the sale date.

```
SELECT  DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,SaleDate,'20170101'),SaleDate)
```